# Node js, Postgresql tables relation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql

I hope someone could offer a suggestion / solution to a challenge I'm currently having. I'm trying to build an admin panel for a healthcare platform. The panel should be accessed by the main admin and also by the hcp admin (healthcare provider). The features on the admin panel would be available depending on the user role: main admin is god so they would have the global admin features like CRUD operations (create/edit/delete) other admins etc, and the hcp admin would have only certain features like managing only users who belong to their hcp (like doctors who work there), managing calendar / appointments and reporting. The stack I'm using is nodejs and postgresql on the back, and react on/ the front. What is the best approach in setting up the relations between tables in postgresql? Or is it better to use NoSQL like MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

This is a multi-faceted question, which touches upon data organization, problem domain modelling and implementation choices. The three are connected in more and less obvious ways, but here are some general guidelines on how to approach a serious design problem such as this:

1. Gather requirements, especially regarding security/compliance. Does the system need to preserve data confidentiality? Do users need to log-in using dedicated usernames/passwords on the DB side, too? (This was mandated for sensitive data in some legislations until GDPR, so do check!) Do you need row-level security so that queries cannot see "other users'" rows?
2. Evaluate your data model, including not just the stored records but their dynamics. Do records need to be removed together and change together? Is data erasure a concern (it could be for a healthcare setting)? Finally, do you already have a strongly-relational model? If yes, it would be awkward and counter-productive to apply a NoSQL, non-relational database to data and processes that clearly benefit from relations and ACID semantics.
3. Consider the available architectural styles. Is the application going to form a classical 3-tier (front-end, back-end, DB) structure, or is there going to be some form of middleware, such as a data access API or proxy? Is there existing middleware that you need to integrate with?
4. Finally, take a look at the use-cases and decide how the permission system fits in. In permissions, your primary concern will be **authorization** - i.e. whether a given subject (*user*) is allowed to perform an operation. This never happens in a vacuum, so you must consider the following contexts:

   - Data retrieval - how to filter the available data to limit visibility. This is often harder (or at least more resource-intensive) than guarding permissions on writes! Typically, this is implemented as additional WHERE conditions, SQL views, or Row-Level Security.
   - Write operations (create/update/delete, calling RPCs) - how to ensure that the subject is authorized to carry out a given operation, and what to do if they aren't (including, in what state will the system be if things fail mid-way? - easier with SQL because you have transactions).
   - External users such as APIs, desktop apps, terminals, medical devices, perhaps even printers? Do those need to connect to the system? If so, will they be able to accomplish their tasks within the boundaries of the permission system laid out, or is another, parallel system (such as capability-based API tokens) needed?

I know this is a lot to consider, but let's face it - designing any functioning software system is hard. One that serves the needs of a sensitive business domain such as healthcare? Doubly so.

Having listed all of the above, a caveat always applies: StackOverflow will never be a viable replacement for actual domain modelling, so that is a part that you and your development team must largely tackle yourself (or outsource!).